# work around for adding alt tag and caption to images in a gallery in Strapi

Tags: strapi, headless-cms

Hi fellow Strapi users,

I was just wondering if there's a work around for adding alt tags and captions to images in an image gallery? I couldn't find anything online and was hoping some of you here might have figured it out (not everyone write blogs :))

thank you!

Comment: Hello! to make sure I well understand your need, you have an attribute `gallery` (I suppose) that is a `Media` type. And your upload many files into?
And for each of these files you would like to add more information like `title`, `alt`... to template your HTML page?

Comment: Hi Jim, that sounds right. Is that possible? I was thinking using a json field to just manually record the values separately but I feel like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the new **groups feature**? I solved the same problem by creating a group with a media and a caption field inside.

[image]

For further information see: https://strapi.io/blog/repeatable-groups-feature

Comment: i didnt think of using groups that way but it might work. I'll give it a try. thank you so much!

Comment: this works perfectly and now i started using groups for any repeatable sections